# func_get_args vs explicit arguments

Tags: php

I have been blissfully unaware of the php function [`func_get_args()`](https://www.php.net/func_get_args), and now that I have discovered it I want to use it everywhere. Are there any limitations of using `func_get_args` as compared to explicit argument declaration in the function definition?

Comment: Not really a major issue, but it doesn't work with IDE's auto-completion. Most IDE's parse PHPDoc comments to work around it though. Is there a reason you don't want to specify the arguments? In most cases, there really is no benefit.

Comment: No limitations beside common sense. Use this function when number of arguments is unknown and don't use it when arguments are strictly defined. That's all.

Comment: The current editor that I use is Dreamweaver 8 (how many of you cringed after reading this?) and it doesn't really do any auto-completes anyway. But to me the greatest advantage in using func_get_args seems to be that if I have to go back and redo a function to add a couple of arguments, there's a good chance that I won't be breaking any existing code that previously relied on explicitly declared arguments.

Comment: You almost certainly *want* things to break when you change the type/number/order of a function's arguments. Avoiding that is the exact *wrong* reason to use `func_get_args`.

Comment: Whenever I need to pass an unknown number of variables to a function, I just have an array as the only argument, and work from there.

Comment: `func_get_args()` [all the things](http://media.tumblr.com/tumblr_lwbh71EWB71qbpbdg.png)!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You shouldn't use `func_get_args` unless you *actually* need it.

If you define a function to take a specific number of arguments, PHP will raise an error if you don't supply enough arguments at call time.

If you take any number of arguments via `func_get_args`, it's up to you to specifically check that all the arguments you're expecting have been passed to your function.

Similarly, you lose the ability to use [type hinting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.typehinting.php), you can't supply [default values](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.arguments.php#functions.arguments.default), and it becomes much harder to tell what arguments your function expects at a glance.

In short, you prevent PHP from helping you catch (potentially difficult to debug) logic errors.

```
function do_stuff(MyClass tmpValue, array $values, $optional = null) {
  // This is vastly better...
}

function do_stuff() {
  // ... than this
}
```

Even if you want to allow a variable number of arguments, you should explicitly specify as many arguments as you can:

```
/**
 * Add some numbers
 * Takes two or more numbers to add together
 */
function add_numbers($num_1, $num_2 /* ..., $num_N */) {
  $total = 0;
  for ($i = 0; $i < func_num_args(); ++$i)
    $total += func_get_arg($i);
  return $total;
}

add_numbers(1,2);   // OK!
add_numbers(1,2,3); // OK!
add_numbers(1)      // Error!
```

Comment: Actually defaults you can do as you can always set your default if the argument is not set, but its way more ugly.

Comment: i would also like to point out that using the `func_get_args` forces you to explicitly check every value required, and would be about ~7 additional lines per function / method.

Comment: @David Manging your own default arguments/type checking isn't at all the same as having PHP do it for you. In this case, default argument values refers explicitly to the built-in feature, not something you cobble together yourself.

Answer (score 1):

- For starters I think it has a performance impact.
- It makes your code much harder to read and understand.
- No automatic error alert will make debugging a pain.

Comment: The performance impact isn't enough to be a dealbreaker, if it exists at all.  It certainly shouldn't be the first thing to consider.  If varargs are the right tool for the job, use them.

Comment: Of cause you should use it if you really need it but as your general method it is a bad idea and even if you disregard any code quality issues there will be a small performance hit, maybe not something you need to think of for a single call, but if Every method uses this, I think it can add up, and he specifically thought of using it for all calls ;)

Comment: Also, all the other arguments only concern the developer but the performance hit, no matter how small is an absolute fact that makes this call at least a tiny bit worse than a straight function with fixed arguments :)

Answer (score 0):

I think auto-completion is harder if not impossible to do for the IDE (it might use the phpdoc @param declaration though)

EDIT: you may use it when your have only one argument : a one-dimensional array, which keys do not matter. It then becomes very handy.

Answer (score 0):

The only limitation I'm aware of is that stuff is harder to check at parse time.  Note that this includes parsers for, say, automated documentation tools, since the functions have args that aren't right there in the function declaration